# Jump Markov process with continuous state space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-process

Suppose I have a particle which moves in the interval $[0,1]$. After an exponential time of rate $1$ the particle (which for instance is in the position $x\in [0,1]$ jumps to the site $y\in [0,1]$ with probability $J(x,y)$, where $J$ is such that $\int_0^1J(x,y)dy=1, \forall x\in [0,1]$. The process which identifies the position of the particle is a Markov process. Is its generator defined as

$$Lf(x)=\int_0^1J(x,y)(f(y)-f(x))dy?$$

Is there any reference in which they talk about Markov processes with continuous state space?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend chapters 7 then 17 of Kallenberg's textbook https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387953137

Your claim is correct, by Proposition 17.2 of the above book.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I will give a look. One think that I don't understand is how I can define the domain of the generator. By proposition 17.2 it seems that is enough the set of functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ measurable and bounded. Do you know why?

Comment: Any markov kernel on a state space $S$ is uniquely determined by its action on on $C_b(S)$, the bounded continuous functions on $S$. Indeed, any probability measure $\mu$ on $S$ is uniquely determined by $\mu(f)$ where $f$ ranges over $C_b(S)$, by a standard approximation argument.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So I need the continuity of the function $f$. Is not sufficient to take for instance $f\in L^2[0,1]$?

Comment: I am looking also at the nook of Either and Kurtz "Markov processes, characterization and convergence"  chapter 4, section 2. It seems that for the domain of the generator it is enough to consider the set of measurable and bounded functions (without the continuity property). Am I wrong?

Comment: Any of these domains can be used interchangeably, by standard approximation arguments. Let $BC\subseteq B\subseteq L^2[0,1]$ denote the set of bounded continuous (resp. bounded) measurable functions. It can be shown that each is a dense subset of the next with respect to the topology in which $f_n\to f$ means that $\mu(f_n)\to \mu(f)$ for all probability measures $\mu$. Thus, knowing the action of a kernel on $BC$ uniquely determines its action on all of $L^2[0,1]$. Hence the smallest domain ($BC$) can be used when it is convenient, or the largest domain ($L^2[0,1]$) or anything in between.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why you say that $B\subseteq L^2([0,1])$?

Comment: If $f$ is a bounded function then $M=\sup |f|$ is finite, and the integral of $f^2$ over $[0,1]$ is bounded by $M^2$ so it belongs to $L^2$.

Comment: Thank you.......